# Does Mario Kart Wii allow more than 32 ghost data slots?

Tags: mario-kart-wii

Recently my ghost data has been full, and I need to delete some ghosts before I can watch some of the world record runs.

On that list, it seems that I had 32 ghosts, so 32 means I cannot have 1 rival ghost + 1 world record ghost for each race track (there are 32 tracks, so it would require 64 ghost slots).

Is there a way to have more than 32?  The data should be small, is there a way to store it on a 2GB SD card, for example?

**Update: I found that I can just create another player and then probably have yet another 32 ghost slots...oh well, I just need to play using that license so as to enable all the cups.**

Answer (score 1):

From the *Mario Kart Wii* instruction booklet, page 12:

> You can save a single ghost per course for each license.  When you succeed in uploading your ghost data for a course, your old ghost is overwritten and can no longer be loaded.

So, **no, you can't save more than 32 ghosts**.